# Interpolation and derivative of 3D data in MATLAB (or Python or C)

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation, spline, derivative

I have three 3D matrices X, Y, and Z that define a matrix V of the same size over some 3D spaces. The matrices are regularly spaced. Now, I'm trying to perform interpolation and also compute the spatial partial derivatives of V i.e for each pixel, compute how V changes with x, y, and z. I have read that interpolating and computing derivatives with splines leads to good results. For instance, I have worked before with splinefit and ppdiff (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13812-splinefit)

How can I use splines that for the datasets I have? Is there some code available preferably in MATLAB (Python and C could work as well) to perform these kind of computations?

Assuming I only want the derivatives at the sampled locations define by X, Y, and Z, could I do 1D spline approximations for each dimension and compute the partial derivatives that way? Maybe that should be a question for the math exchange. It would probably take a while, but it should work right?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try using  [`interp3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html), a 3-D data interpolation function of matlab that support 'spline' as well as other methods. More info in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html)...

Comment: I've used that before, but it doesn't help with differentiation unless I interpolate, perform the gradient and maybe lowpass filter the results

Comment: As in any differentiation  of real data, you always need to smooth it via some filter and\or interpolation before taking the derivative or gradient, this is also true in 1D, so what is really the question? how to take a derivative in a 3D array?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it clicked in my head. I was just trying to look for a better approach to compute the derivative than simple differences. That splinefit function computes the spline approximation and then performs an analytic derivative if I'm not mistaken. It might be somewhat equivalent to interpolate with spline, differentiate with firs differences, and lowpass filter the output, right?